# Is there a way to add style to flask app?

Tags: html, css, flask

I'm trying to add css to my html page in Flask, but it doesn't work.
I tried the code in online editor and it works.

HTML page (results.html):

```
<div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/results.css') }}">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">File name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Result</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="red"> 1 </td>
            <td class="yellow">2</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

This is my css (results.css)

```
table, td, th {
  border: 2px solid;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red {
background-color: #EE3209;
}

.yellow {
background-color: #F0E20A;
}
```

I put css file in "styles" folder, under "static" folder.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to set (in your app.py) where is your static folder:

```
app = Flask(__name__,
        static_url_path='', 
        static_folder='templates/static',
        template_folder='templates')
```

In my example I have a folder "template" then the "static" folder(path ex: myapp/template/static). Inside "static" I created the "CSS" folder (you can also add libraries to the "static"). Since I have my files in it I'll just call them like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycssfile1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycssfile2.css">
```

I hope it can help you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem using: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd>. In this way you perform a hard reload of a web page in Google Chrome.